# How to Set a Control's user-editable property with a Button click only in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, eventtrigger

Specifically, I'm trying to create a "reset" button that will set a slider's value to zero.  I don't want code-behind because the template will be customizable.

I tried the following.  Without `FillBehavior="Stop"` the slider is no longer movable by the user.  With `FillBehavior="Stop"` the value immediately returns to the preceding value (giving the appearance it does nothing at all)

```
    <Slider Name="MySlider" Minimum="-5" Maximum="5" Value="{Binding FloatProperty}"></Slider>
    <Button Content="Reset">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MySlider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value">
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

I also tried using a DataTrigger on the Slider binding to the button's IsPressed property, but I wasn't able to get that to work either.  It would return to the prior value.

Note that the Value of the Slider is bound to a property of the data.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your use of an Animation - Animations usually mean *"Shift the target property from A to B over a time period of C"*, while what you are looking to do is simply *"Set bound value to X"*. Depending on  what this XAML represents (UserControl containing both a Slider and a Button, loose XAML bound to a specific DataContext, etc), I would either use an ICommand to reset the the value, or just use code behind. I don't see anything wrong with using a code behind file if I have a Click event in a Template and only plan on modifying UI-specific values.

Comment: @Rachel, Animation was chosen because it almost works and meets the criteria of avoiding a handful of changes to the underlying class displayed by this template. Yes, the intent is to allow skinning via loose xaml, and if the values could be changed via xaml, the customizer could define what "reset" means, among other things.

Comment: @user2149714 This is a bug outright. Slider becomes frozen and doesn't respond to mouseclick, bounded-value.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan - Not a bug. Please see my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor edits to your XAML seems to do the trick. You need to filter the Button.Click events by a specific source name, like shown below. Also, removing the Binding from Slider.Value seems to help.

I'm not quite sure how best to maintain the Binding and still be able to make this work right.

```
<Slider Name="MySlider"
        Maximum="5"
        Minimum="-5"/>
<Button Name="myButton" Content="Reset">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="myButton">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MySlider"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                                     To="0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

If the goal is to have Slider.Value data bound to something, like...

```
<Slider Value="{Binding FloatProperty}"/>
```

... then I suspect (though I'm not 100% sure) that what you are trying to do may not be possible.

First, let me explain why you are seeing the slider being "frozen". This is not quite a bug - I just needed to read the docs a bit carefully to realize what was going on.

When FillBehavior is set to Stop, the Animation will revert the value (to whatever it was before the Animation started) when the TimeLine is completed.

On the other hand, when FillBehavior is HoldEnd (which is the default behavior you get when FillBehavior is not specified explicitly), the DoubleAnimation will continue to **hold** the end value and  protect against changes from other sources (like slider move by hand). So every time you move the slider, the Animation resets it back to 0 becuase of HoldEnd. This is why you see the slider acting as if it were "frozen" at 0.

I investigated using a DataTrigger on Button.IsPressed = True as an alternative. This is typically done within a Style or a ControlTemplate - and it would look something like this:

```
         <Slider Maximum="5"
                Minimum="-5"
                Value="{Binding FloatProperty}">
            <Slider.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Slider x:Name="Slider"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding Maximum}"
                                Minimum="{TemplateBinding Minimum}"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                Path=Value,
                                                Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Button x:Name="ResetButton"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Content="Reset" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ResetButton, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Slider" Property="Value" Value="0" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Slider.Template>
        </Slider>
```

Unfortunately, the [Dependency Property Value Precedence rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx) hold that TemplatedParent template properties have a higher precedence than Triggers and Style setters. Because of this, clicking on the 'Reset' button would momentarily change the slider value to 0, but would be immediately reset back to its original value that is backed by the corresponding Binding.

Having exhausted Animation and DataTriggers, I'm lead to conclude that this may not be possible. That said, given the vast range of capabilities present in WPF, I could very well be wrong...

---

Edit: 12/5/2015

I think I have a solution that will satisfy your key requirement - namely allowing a designer to modify the UI, including the meaning of "reset" Value of the Slider. That said, this solution requires code-behind - but such a code-behind would not prevent the XAML to be fully expressive of your intent.

The idea is to write a **Behavior**, and use that Behavior to associate a Button with a Slider, and indicate that this Button should trigger the 'reset' action.

The basic outline of the Behavior looks like this:

```
    /// <remarks>
    /// Requires System.Windows.Interactivity.dll to be 
    /// added to the References section of the Project
    /// </remarks>
    public class SliderResetBehavior: Behavior<Button>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            // AssociatedObject refers to a Button instance
            // to which this Behavior is attached
            AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Upon receiving a Click event, reset the Slider 
        /// </summary>
        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Slider != null)
            {
                Slider.Value = ResetValue;
            }
        }

        #region Dependency Property - ResetValue

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores a double that will act as the definition of 'reset' 
        /// value for the Slider associated with this Behavior. 
        /// </summary>
        public double ResetValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ResetValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ResetValueProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ResetValue.
        // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ResetValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ResetValue", 
                typeof(double), 
                typeof(SliderResetBehavior), 
                new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Maintains a System.Windows.Controls.Slider object upon 
        /// which this Behavior will act upon. 
        /// </summary>
        #region Dependency Property - Slider 
        public Slider Slider
        {
            get { return (Slider)GetValue(SliderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SliderProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Slider.
        // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Slider", 
                typeof(Slider), 
                typeof(SliderResetBehavior), 
                new PropertyMetadata(default(Slider)));

        #endregion
    }
```

The XAML can now be quite simple, like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="Slider" Minimum="-5" Maximum="5" Value="{Binding SliderValue}"/>
    <!-- 
       Requires xmlns entries like this:
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<Namespace containing SliderResetBehavior>"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    -->
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Reset">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:SliderResetBehavior ResetValue="0" Slider="{Binding ElementName=Slider}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This XAML shown above retains the key properties of being fully customizable by a designer using loose XAML only, and allowing data-binding of Slider.Value as well.

Comment: As you note, this doesn't work with binding.  With binding, it has the same "locking" effect I noted when removing FillBehavior from my non-solution.

Comment: The best I can tell, I don't think that you can do this if Slider.Value is bound to another value.

Animations wouldn't help - when FillBehavior is Stop, the Animation will revert the value when the TimeLine is completed. When FillBehavior is HoldEnd (default), the Animation will continue to hold the end value and  protect against changes from other sources (like slider move by hand). This is why you see the slider acting as if it were "frozen" at 0.

Comment: I do like your suggestion of using a behavior.  I believe the behavior can be provided by the author customizing the UI if needed, rather than requiring a command on the existing object / code.  I've upvoted your post, but I don't see it as an answer, as the question appears unanswerable.  I'm fairly new to posting on Stack Overflow.  Perhaps I should change the original question to, "Can .... be done in xaml, while also binding the property"  In which case the answer appears to be, no.